# Array of contracts stays empty

Tags: contract-development, arrays

I am desperately trying to manage an array of contracts from a parent contract. Going back to basics, I have implemented the code coming from [Pushing a contract to an array in another contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/129925/pushing-a-contract-to-an-array-in-another-contract) witch roughly does what I want.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

contract Dog {
  string public name;
  constructor(string memory _name){
       name = _name;
   }
}

contract Human {
  Dog[] public dogs;
  uint public currDogs;

  function addDog() public {
    dogs.push(new Dog("test"));
    currDogs++;
  }
}
```

Compilation using solc: solc Human.sol --bin --abi -o . --overwrite

Deployment using a JS script similar to the one described in the doc: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy

Going to the JavaScript console, I do the following:

```
> var abi = [{"inputs":[],"name":"addDog","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currDogs","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"dogs","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract Dog","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
undefined
> var cnt = web3.eth.contract(abi);
undefined
> 
> var cntinst = cnt.at('0x43d0A1BAC182803587ae9bFF6a4EbF27f3600900');
undefined
> cntinst.addDog({from: eth.accounts[0], gas:3000000});
"0xf9426240a47cb6d0f6f58b47f8b54206bcd665079a6a421f088d41c40b22b5f4"
> cntinst.dogs.length.valueOf()
0
> cntinst.dogs.length
0
> cntinst.dogs[0].name
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
        at <eval>:1:1(4)
```

The question is: Why is my array "dogs" always empty?

Comment: Where are you executing the code? Perhaps, from the geth console? Geth's console uses an web3 v0.20. In that case you have to use `cntinst.dogs(index)`. For web3 version 1.xx and above `cntinst.dogs` doesn't exists, it was replaced by `cntinst.methods.dogs(index)`.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call function `addDog` in your `Human` contract it will always deploy new contract of Dog in blockchain and return its address and push it into dogs array, to understand it better I modified your contract little bit so you can check it.

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

contract Dog {
  string public name;
  constructor(string memory _name){
       name = _name;
   }

   function getName() public view returns(string memory) {
       return name;
   }

}

interface Dogs {
    function getName() external view returns(string memory);
}

contract Human {
  Dog[] public dogs;
  uint public currDogs;

  function addDog(string memory _name) public {
    dogs.push(new Dog(_name));
    currDogs++;
  }

  function getName(uint index) public view returns(string memory) {
      address indexAddress = address(dogs[index]);
      return Dogs(indexAddress).getName();
  }
}
```

- Call `addDog` function with dog name and it will deploy new contract and store address of new contract into the `dogs` array.
- Check the length of `currDogs`.
- To verify the address call `dogs` varible and pass the `currDogs value - 1` so it would be `0`, and you will get contract address.
- To verify the name you can use two methods .

1. would be directly call the `getName` function and pass the value of `0` in it. you will get same name as you used during calling `addDog` function.
2. would be using remix `at Address` feature

- [image]
- In above image select your Dog contract and use the address you got from `dogs variable call` and call the method `getName`

Comment: Following the doc (https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html)
The Contract Application Binary Interface (ABI) is the standard way to interact with contracts in the Ethereum ecosystem, both from outside the blockchain and for contract-to-contract interaction.

If I am not wrong, it does mean that I have to provide at some point the ABI of Dog so that Human is able to interact wit Dog contract.

Question is how?